# Object arrays in matlab passed from c#

Tags: c#, matlab

So I have this object in C#, which will contain ints and bools (doubles and logicals)

```
object[,] matrixData = new object[iDimensions[0], iDimensions[1]];
```

and I pass it to matlab:

```
matlab.PutWorkspaceData("matrixData", "base", matrixData);
```

Matlab sees this as a cell array of arrays.  Which is inconvenient since I now cannot use these values for anything.  I guess I need to convert these into a numerical array - although in truth I'd be happier to retain the strong typing and just lose the array within each cell.

So, for example:

```
temp = cell(1,4)

temp{1,1} = [0.5]
temp{1,2} = [1==1]
temp{1,3} = [7424.356]
temp{1,4} = [31]
```

and I want to have:

```
output = [0.5, 1==1, 7424.356, 31]
```

So my current implementation is pretty crass:

```
cellfun(@decellify,CashFlowBasisMatrixData);
```

where

```
function decellified = decellify(object)

if  isa(object,'logical')
    decellified = +object;
end

if  isa(object,'float')
    decellified = object;
end    

if  isa(object,'char')
    decellified = -2;
end

end
```

Is there a better way?  If I do the conversion to doubles in C# how do I 'un-array' each element?

Thanks,
Nt